# Start Networking at login

Tags: networking, netctl

**What I would like to do:**

I would like to start my wireless network after login (As apposed to starting at boot).
Using my login credentials to run the command: `sudo netctl start network`. Instead of needing to Login once, then login my credentials a second time to start networking, at the same time I would prefer not having my system bootup with networking enabled.

**The crux:**

I thought I could just add it to `.xinit` but startx doesn't require sudo, however netctl does and therefore will not run.

I then thought about running it in my `.bash_profile` but that doesn't seem to work, for the same reason.

**Is there a way to run networking at login, while just supplying login credentials once?**

OS: Arch Linux

Comment: What distribution are you running, because I remember I had to do the exact opposite on my laptop (but I'm not sure if that was for Ubuntu 12.04 or Linux Mint 17)

Comment: I am using Arch Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure `sudo` to allow you to run the command without a password:

As root:

```
# visudo
```

append the following:

```
<username> ALL = NOPASSWD: netctl start network, netctl stop network
```

where `<username>` is your username (without `<` and `>`) or `ALL` to allow everyone to do this. You can also stipulate a group by preceding it with a `%` (eg `%admin`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods you tried but allow the user to run the command without asking for a password.

You would need to edit the visudo file to allow one user to run this command without asking for a password.

Run `sudo EDITOR=nano visudo`
add a line at the end as follows:

```
username ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/netctl
```

After logging out and in again you can try using your `.bash_profile` to start the command. Include `sudo` before the command.